# ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: Illegal plugin name

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to use https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin

My E.S version is 1.4.4 , and as soon as i run the first command  :

```
bin/plugin install https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin/blob/master/download/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-v1.9.2_es-v2.3.2.zip?raw=true
```

I end up with :

```
Message:
   Error while installing plugin, reason: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: Illegal plugin name:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running ES 1.4.4 you cannot install the version for ES 2.3.2.
Also you need to specify the URL using the `--url`  switch

Try this, it will work

```
bin/plugin --install readonlyrest --url 'https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin/blob/master/download/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-v1.3_es-v1.4.1.zip?raw=true'
```

See all available versions of that plugin [here](https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin/tree/master/download)